# Windows Phone Online database

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-8

I have a winodws phone game and I would like to add an online classification for the players. I tried to register to Azure, but it requires a credit card which I don't have, so, can you suggest me some other ways? I already have a database online, I need the code to connect with it, which isn't easy to find...Could you please help me?

Comment: What kind of _database_ do you have?

Comment: I have a MySql service with a SQL database!

Comment: What kind of web server do you have .Net Based or Linux Based? and What kind of your DB?

Comment: Take a look at http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us/partners

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone application you cannot directly connect to a database.Instead you can have a local database in your application,and you can update the local database with the values of online database.For this purpose you need webservice to be developed in your webserver,and access the webservice to update the local database.